# Android Module with Google Play Conflict during build

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am using a Google Analytics module along with Ti.CloudPush. But the issue is that while building the application using 5.2.0.GA  I am getting the following error:

```
    [ERROR] :  Failed to run dexer:
    [ERROR] :  
    [ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamic/LifecycleDelegate;
    [ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller;
    [ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller$ProviderInstallListener;
    [ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller$1;
    [ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/AccountChangeEventsResponse;
    [ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil;
    [ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/UserRecoverableAuthException;
    [ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/AccountChangeEvent;
    [ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthException;
    [ERROR] :  
    [ERROR] :  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    [ERROR] :  java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    [ERROR] :      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:608)
    [ERROR] :      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    [ERROR] :      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    [ERROR] :      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    [ERROR] :      at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    [ERROR] :  Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    [ERROR] :      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:600)
    [ERROR] :      ... 4 more
```

It seems to be conflict with the Google Play library. When I did further analysis, the Google Play library that comes with the CloudPush module is ~700KB where as the one present in the extras folder in Android SDK is ~5MB.

So the question now is, if one of the CloudPush module is required to be removed, then which one should be removed, or is there any other way to resolve the issue.

**Update 1 (Mar 01, 2016)**

From version 6.5 onwards, we can create individual silo for respective requirements. Hence the base is ~700KB and the entire package is ~5MB. Now, the question that remains is how can issue be resolved where two separate modules use Google Play services.

**Update 2 (Mar 01, 2016)**

There is google-play-services-analytics.jar which seems to fit the requirement. As to whether that can be used for not, needs investigation. If that can be integrated, then it will be an excellent option.

**Update 3 (Mar 03, 2016)**

As recommended by Fokke, I will try to remove the JAR files from TiCloudPush and keep only one in the Google Analytics module and try it out. Also, along with it, I will try to keep the JAR in TiCloudPush and put only analytics.jar in the analytics module to see how it works out. Will update once I get the response.

**Update 4 (Mar 05, 2016)**

I tried to use google-play-services-analytics.jar along with CloudPush module during the build, but it is still giving the dex error.

**Update 5 (Mar 06, 2016)**

If I remove google-play-services-base.jar from CloudPush module then the dex error is resolved. The google-play-services-base.jar is conflicting with google-play-services-analytics.jar even if they are from the same version. It looks like there other than removing all the google play services JAR references from all the modules except one and keeping the entire (bigger version JAR) in that module seems to be the only solution as of now.

**Update 6 (Mar 07, 2016)**

It seems I was using an incorrect version of google-play-services-analytics.jar. If I use the proper version (https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Ti.GA/tree/master/Android/lib) which I found here, then the dex issue gets resolved. Hence, the Ti Modules remain untouched and I have to only add this module in the 3rd party analytics jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titanium currently doesn't handle duplicate libraries well:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/MOD-1985

Until this has been fixed, you will have to manually delete the jar from either of the modules.

These JIRA tickets have some information you might be able to use to decide which JAR to keep:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22google%20play%20services%20conflict%22

Comment: One question. If I remove the JAR files form the CloudPush module folder and keep the latest Android Google Play Services JAR in my module, then will CloudPush module work properly? I have the Google Play Services JAR of higher version than the one specified in TiModule.xml of CloudPush.

Comment: I also went through the second link which you shared and it seemed that if we move to older versions of the module then it might solve the issue (I have not yet tried it). I want to use the latest version of the modules, hence will be glad if you can clarify my query in the first comment to your answer.

Comment: We have not tested CloudPush with Google Play Service later than what we include, but I'd just test and find out.

Comment: Thanks. You can also try out Update-6 approach too.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of any two external modules which uses same .jar files.
I solved this issue by locating each modules installed folders then deleting that common jar from anyone of the module folder.Then rebuild the solution it will work.In my case i had issue with `ti.map` module and gcm push notification module.

Comment: So you deleted the google-play-services-base.jar from one of the jar and then rebuild the application. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, not sure about the file name.I had same jar on both modules.Deleted one.

Comment: Ok, got it. Fokke is also of the same opinion. I will be trying it out in this weekend and confirm.

Comment: you are welcome.i was messed up with same issue for weeks time and finally i figured the issue myself.

Comment: I tried the approach and the build seems to be working fine. I have not yet tested it. I was also thinking that did you remove all the jars and replaced them (in one of the module) with the google-play-services jar that comes as part of the Android SDK (inside extras folder)?

Comment: I just removed the jar from one module which is common in both the modules.For ex if a.jar is present in both mod1 and mod2 folders, i removed a.jar from mod1 folder.Also please mark right answer if it helped.